# C# structure does not use new instantiation problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I found it compiled in the latest visual studio 2022, but what is the reason? code show as below:

```
  public struct Point 
  { 
    public int X; 
  } 

  Point a; 
  a.X = 400; 
  Console. WriteLine(a.X);
```

Report an error Severity Code Description Item File Line Suppressed Status Error CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable "a" ConsoleApp1 C:\Users\tangsonghua\source\repos\Solution1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs 6 Activity

According to Microsoft's official documentation, this should not happen, what's going on

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct

Comment: According to my test, your code is fine. Can you provide the .net version number used and the version of Visual Studio, or are there other assemblies being referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected this code will compile and run. This has been true [at least as far back as 4.7,](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4aHhzt) and really as far back as I can remember (I've been using .Net since shortly before 2.0 came out in 2005).

`struct` is used for value types that cannot ever be `null`. When you declare a variable with a struct type, if you don't assign anything to the variable you have a value where each member is the default for the type. It's why, for example, you don't have to create an instance with `new` when declaring things like `int` or `DateTime`.

The semantics are also different when passing struct vs class to methods. Think about this code:

```
void SomeFunction(someType Foo)
{
    Foo.stringField = "two";
}

var Foo = new someType(); // legal for both struct and class
Foo.stringField = "one";
SomeFunction(Foo);
Console.WriteLine(Foo.stringField);
```

If `someType` is a reference type (`class`), the result on the Console is "two". But if it's a value type (`struct`), the result on the Console is "one". This is because the value type is copied when passing to the method, and the field change is made on the copy. When the reference variable is passed to the method a copy is also made... but only of the reference. The variable in the method is a separate variable from the calling code with it's own reference, but it refers to the same object, so when the method changes the field it also impacts the calling code.

See it happen:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/KwBjF2

Comment: "if you don't assign anything to the variable you have a value where each member is the default for the type" false. You can't interact with a the members of a structure, in a local variable, until all fields have been initialised, perhaps by calling the default constructor.  It's only structures in class fields that will have the default constructor implicitly called.

Comment: You can assign to `a.X` then the C# compiler will consider the variable to be initialised as all fields have been assigned. Comment out that assignment, and you will have a compiler error.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct "If all instance fields of a structure type are accessible, you can also instantiate it without the new operator. In that case you must initialize all instance fields before the first use of the instance"

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of protection mom levels